# Pandas- DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 5 columns, where the column i need to aggregate is of a string, and has NaN values.
I tried replacing the nan values with 0 and then converting the column to numeric but still getting "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate" when performing a gruopby and aggregate function.

```
df.head()

df['Profit (in millions)']= df['Profit(in millions)'].str.replace('N.A', '0')
pd.to_numeric(df['Profit (in millions)'], errors ='ignore')
df_new = df.groupby('Year')['Profit (in millions)'].median()
df_new.head(7)
```

[image]

error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems, you forget assign back and if `errors ='ignore'` and at least one non paseable value in column it return column with no change:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Profit (in millions)'], errors ='ignore')
```

[`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

> **errors** : {'ignore', 'raise', 'coerce'}, default 'raise'
>
> If 'raise', then invalid parsing will raise an exception
> If 'coerce', then invalid parsing will be set as NaN
> If '**ignore**', then invalid parsing will return the input

So use `errors ='coerce'` and return output back to column:

```
df['Profit (in millions)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Profit (in millions)'], errors ='coerce')
```

Comment: when i use coerce and i want to aggregate, i get the same error:

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas `str.replace` only works with strings and will replace non-strings with NAN which is why you are getting that error.

An alternative method to replace strings with numbers is to use `map` and a lambda function. You do this before any data aggregation:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['Price'] = [1,2,3,'N.A.']
df['Year']  = [2001, 2001, 2002, 2002]
print(df)

df['Price'] = df.Price.map(lambda x: 0.0 if type(x) is str else x)
print(df)

df_new = df.groupby('Year')['Price'].median()
print(df_new)
```

[image]